# Where to start a worker thread in Next.js?

Tags: multithreading, next.js, initialization

I want to start a worker thread in Next.js. Next.js has no `main` function, so I doubt where to start the worker.

The best places I see are in initialization either of:

- the top-level widget `page.tsx` (in widget initialization, namely in `useEffect(..., [])`
- the root layout `layout.tsx` (also in widget initialization, namely in `useEffect(..., [])`

So, where to start the worker thread?